# Debian Jessie JavaFX MediaPlayer : Could not create player

Tags: java, javafx, debian

I get this exception while running a java app with Ant configuration.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
```

Here is my code :

```java
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final Scene scene = new Scene(((Viewer)viewer).getPanel());
    Media theme = new Media(getHostServices().getDocumentBase() + "src/sound/theme_bttf.mp3");
    new MediaPlayer(theme).play();
}
```

Does anyone have an idean on how to solve this ?

I run it on **Debian Jessie 64bits** with **Gnome 3.14.1** and **Java** :

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Edit :**

Here is the stack trace i get when doing `ant run` :

```
run:
 [echo] ================ Run Object Main ================
 [java] Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
 [java] Exception in Application start method
 [java] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 [java] Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
 [java]     at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
 [java]     at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
 [java]     at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
 [java]     at alpha.Main.start(Main.java:71)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 [java]     at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 [java]     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 [java]     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
 [java]     ... 1 more
 [java] Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
 [java]     at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
 [java]     at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
 [java]     at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
 [java]     ... 11 more
 [java] Exception running application alpha.Main
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

**Edit 2 :**

I have `libavcodec56`, `libavformat56` and GLIB 2.42.1 installed.

```
# pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
2.42.1
```

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace.

Comment: @Puce Just added stack trace to my post

Answer (score 2):

From the [Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html)
section of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

> You must install GLIB 2.28 in order to run JavaFX Media.
>
> You must install the following in order to support AAC audio, MP3
>   audio, H.264 video, and HTTP Live Streaming:
>
> - libavcodec53 and libavformat53 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 or equivalent.

[...]

> - VP6 video support does not require any third party modules.
> - On Linux platforms, installing libavformat automatically causes libavcodec to be installed.

Please double-check you have all the required libraries installed.

Comment: @Senorihl  I guess you have GLIB 2.28 installed as well then?

Comment: I guess ... what is the name i can use with aptitude ?

Comment: and GLIB 2.42.1 is installed

Comment: @Senorihl If you think you've setup everything correctly but you're still getting the error, please file an issue here: http://bugs.java.com/

Answer (score 0):

While the argument to `Media`'s constructor is a `String`, it must be formatted as a valid URI.  So instead of:

```
Media theme = new Media(getHostServices().getDocumentBase() + "src/sound/theme_bttf.mp3");
```

try this:

```
Media theme = new Media(new File(getHostServices().getDocumentBase() + "src/sound/theme_bttf.mp3").toUri().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a java bug in this case. Try downloading the new version which's been fixed (I downloaded the jdk 8u102).
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html