# MediaPlayer Can't Find Audio?

Tags: java, file, user-interface, ubuntu, javafx

I've set up a media player that plays a certain media file from a path in the program's directory. This runs in the `Init` method of a Netbeans JavaFX application (Basically it calls init after loading the `FXML` graph)

```
public static final Path APPLICATION_AUDIOTRACK = Paths.get("Audio", "L.I.F.T.mp3");
```

```
Media media = new Media(APPLICATION_AUDIOTRACK.toUri().toString());
this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
this.mediaPlayer.play();
```

This works just fine (Audio plays, everything good) in the Netbeans environment, but when I try to run the standalone jar (After copying the jar from the dist folder after clean & build to the main program directory) I get this when running it:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at com.protonmail.sarahszabo.formattool.core.Main_PanelController.lambda$initialize$2(Main_PanelController.java:190)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 9 more
```

Some notes about this:

1. Nowhere here does there appear to be anything wrong with the code per se, I get the feeling that i'm missing something subtle.
2. The jar was moved to the main program directory (As opposed to the dist folder that Netbeans makes automagically). I don't think that this is a library issue either (I do have some dependencies on Apache IO Commons), but the `lib` folder was moved as well, and this doesn't appear to be related to any lib issue as far as I can tell.
3. I'm running this on Kubuntu 17.10. I've heard that previously x64 *buntu systems were unsupported on JRE 8, but I think that that post is dated (Over a year old: [JavaFX media player on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164044/javafx-media-player-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

**EDIT 0:** I have `glib-2.0` & `libavcodec57` installed (Upon recommendation of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872444/2058221).

Comment: `Paths.get("Audio", "L.I.F.T.mp3")` is a relative path, which means it depends on the *current directory* of the Java process.  That may or may not be the directory where the .jar file resides.  For this reason, it’s best to embed the file in your .jar;  such a .jar entry is called an application resource, and you access it not as a Path, but as a URL returned by [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @VGR Hmm, where is the default Jar perspective then? I assumed that it set itself to wherever the jar file is. The only reason why I moved it in the first place is because I figured that Netbeans set the default perspective to the project folder. I also tried calling `toAbsolutePath`, before the `.toURI`, but no luck.

Comment: You have no guarantee of what the current directory is.  That’s why you should not rely on it.  If you place the mp3 file inside your .jar file as a resource, you no longer have to worry about where your .jar is located.

Comment: @VGR Is there any way to do that with Netbeans? I've never done such a thing.